# Virtual functions on classes derived form structs

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, virtual

I have a class that derives from a C struct. The class does not do anything special, other than initialization in the constructor, deinitialization function during the destructor, and a few other methods that call into C functions. Basically, it's a run-of-the-mill wrapper. Using GCC, it complained that my destructor was not virtual, so I made it that. Now I run into segfaults.

```
/* C header file */
struct A
{
  /* ... */
}

// My C++ code
class B : public A
{
public:
  B() { /* ... init ... */ }
  virtual ~B() { /* ... deinit ... */ }

  void do()
  {
    someCFunction(static_cast<A *>(this));
  }
};
```

I was always under the assumption that the `static_cast` would return the correct pointer to the base class, pruning off the virtual table pointer. So this may not be the case, since I get a segfault in the C function.

By removing the `virtual` keyword, the code works fine, except that I get a gcc warning. What is the best work around for this? Feel free to enlighten me :).

Comment: No, I cannot. It's a public C header.

Comment: Why not use a class instead of a struct? The difference is obvious yet the same goal is achieved.

Comment: Is this a correct representation of your problem? Why isnt      someCFunction(static_cast<A *>(this));  good without the cast? A sliced object.

Comment: Because when you pass the this keyword into a C function, it brings along with it the vtable. C cannot deal with vtables.

Comment: And you know for a fact the segfault happens in the cast, not the function? Also the vtable is not present for pointers to A.

Comment: Segfault happens in the function, not the cast.

Comment: I added comments to you code to make it clear that the struct and the class declarations are in different files.

Comment: Can you show the prototype for someCFunction?

Comment: @MarkP: No, it doesn't. A `B*` will automatically, and safely, convert to an `A*`. The cast is redundant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the actual problem is somewhere else and unrelated to this. None of the themes raised in the answers seem to apply to whatever problem you're experiencing.

Comment: Why does gcc complain about `B` not having a virtual destructor? Maybe `B` has something special that causes both the warning and the strange behavior of `static_cast`? BTW `do` is a bad name for a function ;)

Comment: One more thing: Any time you're trying to reason about the *language* C++ and how to use it correctly, and you find yourself thinking about a "vtable", you're probably Thinking About It Wrong. There's no "vtable" in the language.

Comment: May this is not an issue but .... `do` is a keyword (and hence should be reserved). Is the compiler doing messy thing because of that?

Just try another name

Comment: 'do' was not intentional. The function name could be foo, if you'd like. The soneCFunction() does direct manipulation of the struct, and is compiled in a C library. I have a feeling that adding extern "c" around the struct's include might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the explicit and implicit conversion to `A*` are safe. There is neither need for an explicit cast, nor is it going to introduce vtables anywhere, or anything like that. The language would be fundamentally unusable if this were not the case.

> I was always under the assumption that the static_cast would return
>   the correct pointer to the base class, pruning off the virtual table
>   pointer.

Is absolutely correct.

The destructor need be `virtual` only if `delete ptr;` is called where `ptr` has type `A*`- or the destructor invoked manually. And it would be `A`'s destructor that would have to be virtual, which it isn't.

Whatever the problem is in your code, it has nothing to do with the code shown. You need to expand your sample considerably.

Comment: This is probably the only sensible answer in the light of the poorly presented and researched question.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor of base classes should be virtual. Otherwise, there's a chance that you run into undefined behavior. This is just a speculation, as the code is not enough to tell the actual reason.

Try making the destructor of `A` virtual and see if it crashes.

Note that a `class` and a `struct` are the same thing, other than default access level, so the fact that one's a class and the other a struct has nothing to do with it.

EDIT: If `A` is a C-struct, use composition instead of inheritance - i.e. have an `A` member inside of `B` instead of extending it. There's no point of deriving, since polymorphism is out of the question.

Comment: I cannot, it's defined in a public C header.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation as to why inheriting from a C struct is not desired? I understand that when a virtual keyword is introduced, the virtual table is added. Does that also add a vtable to the struct? (as in, when doing a static_cast, does it return A with a vtable?)

Comment: Why undef behavior if `~A` is not virtual? At least if he uses `A*` to handle a `B` object, the memory occupied by `B` will not be deallocated when the object is destroyed. I cannot see the undefined behavior implication! (just real curiosity).

Comment: @MarkP: No, the code you describe should work fine.  But composition instead of inheritance will prevent other errors that you may have that could be causing the segfualt.

Comment: @puller it's undefined behavior if you call `delete` on an A*. That's why I said it's *possible*, not certain.

Comment: @MooingDuck well, it's not ok if `someCFunction` deletes the pointer.

Comment: @MarkP it's not desired because you should favor composition over inheritance (google this, there are tons of reasons), and you gain nothing from inheritance if A is not polymorphic.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes, sure, but still, why undefined? There will just be pieces of `B` leaking the memory. Do we call this undefined? It seems quite predictable instead.

Comment: @puller because that's what the standard says. If you delete an object of a derived type through a pointer to a base type, and the base type doesn't have a virtual destructor, it's undefined behavior. It's not a memory leak, but UB.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `static_cast` works. A pointer to an object continues to be the same pointer, just with a different type. In this case, you're converting a pointer to a derived type (`B`) into a pointer to the base type (`A`).

My guess is that casting the pointer does not actually change the pointer value, i.e., it's still pointing to the same memory address, even though it's been cast into an `A*` pointer type. Remember that `struct` and `class` are synonyms in C++.

As @Luchian stated, if you're mixing C and C++, it's better to keep the plain old C structs (and their pointers) as plain old C structs, and use type composition instead of inheritance. Otherwise you're mixing different pointer implementations under the covers. There is no guarantee that the internal arrangement of the C struct and the C++ class are the same.

**UPDATE**

You should surround the C struct declaration with an `extern "C"` specification, so that the C++ compiler knows that the struct is a pure C struct:

```
extern "C"
{
    struct A
    {
        ...
    };
}
```

*Or:*

```
extern "C"
{
#include "c_header.h"
}
```

Comment: So does inheriting from a C struct with a class that is virtual change the layout of the struct itself?

Comment: If nothing else, it adds a hidden `vtable` member.

Comment: @Loadmaster: no, the struct will not have a vtable.  `static_cast` should return a pointer to the `A`, without the vtable.  The `static_cast` should not be an issue.

Comment: I'll try adding the extern statement around my include. Perhaps it will help. Otherwise, I'll end up encapsulating the struct instance instead of inheriting from it.